# Remove rows that do not differ from the previous row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

Suppose I have a table that records changes to my database over time:

```
TimeOfChange FieldA FieldB FieldC
-------------------------------------
2019-01-01     A1     B1     C1       /*(R1)*/
2019-01-02     A2     B2     C1       /*(R2)*/
2019-01-03     A2     B2     C1       /*(R3)*/
2019-01-05     A1     B1     C2       /*(R4)*/
2019-01-07     A1     B1     C1       /*(R5)*/
```

My database has many rows where nothing significant changed, eg row (R3) is the same as (R2).
I would like to remove these rows. I have found many references on how to use a common table expression to remove duplicate rows from the table. So it's possible to remove the duplicate (ignoring the TimeOfChange column) rows. But this will remove (R5) as well because it is the same as R1. I only want to remove the rows that have the same ABC values as the previous row, when ordered by the TimeOfChange column. How do I do that?

edit: You can assume that TimeOfChange values are all unique

Comment: What about when there are gaps in the TimeOfChange values? Would a `2019-01-07, A1, B1, C1` be removed because of the `2019-01-05` data if no `2019-01-06` exists?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Uueerdo - yes, I've only put sequential dates for a simple example, in fact it is a datetime column with many rows on the same date (different times), and many missing days - it is just used to force an order, Delete rows only if they have the same ABC values as the previous row.

Comment: Your example should be representative of your actual data. I would stop using the expression "previous row", it is actually making things less clear. You first defined row by order of TimeOfChange; but that becomes ambiguous when TimeOfChange is not unique.

Comment: Are TimeOfChange values guaranteed unique? The ordering includes the time, and is not `ORDER BY DATE(TimeOfChange)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the TimeOfChange is unique, you can do:

```
delete
from data
where TimeOfChange in (
  select TimeOfChange
  from (
    select d2.TimeOfChange
    from data d1
      join data d2
    where d2.TimeOfChange in (
      select min(x.TimeOfChange) 
      from data x
      where x.TimeOfChange>d1.TimeOfChange
    ) and d1.FieldA=d2.FieldA and d1.FieldB=d2.FieldB and d1.FieldC=d2.FieldC
  ) as q
);
```

So you first want to determine which rows are the "next" and then check if the "next" has the same values as the "current". For those the "next" would form a result set that you want to use in `DELETE`. The `select * from data` is there to circumvent the reuse of the table in `DELETE` and in the subquery.

You probably will get much better performance if you separate the logic into a stored procedure and store the id's for rows to be deleted into a temp table.

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w2cbAVNVSMPWoaVp9utZYc/0)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming, you really meant "when the same A, B, C occurred on the most recent day prior that had any data", this should be usable to identify the rows that need removed:

```
SELECT t2.TimeOfChange, t2.FieldA, t2.FieldB, t2.FieldC
FROM (
   SELECT tMain.TimeOfChange, tMain.FieldA, tMain.FieldB, tMain.FieldC
      , MAX(tPrev.TimeOfChange) AS prevTimeOfChange
   FROM t AS tMain
   LEFT JOIN t AS tPrev ON t.TimeOfChange> tPrev.TimeOfChange
   GROUP BY tMain.TimeOfChange, tMain.FieldA, tMain.FieldB, tMain.FieldC
) AS t2
INNER JOIN t AS tPrev2 
   ON t2.prevTimeOfChange = tPrev2.TimeOfChange
   AND t2.FieldA = tPrev2.FieldA 
   AND t2.FieldB = tPrev2.FieldB 
   AND t2.FieldC = tPrev2.FieldC
```

This can then be used in a DELETE with some indirection to force a temp table to be created.

```
DELETE td 
FROM t AS td 
WHERE (td.TimeOfChange, td.FieldA, td.FieldB, td.FieldC) 
  IN (SELECT * FROM ([the query above]) AS tt) -- Yes, you have to wrap the query from above in a select * so mysql will not reject it.
;
```

However, after getting this far, what happens when....

```
2019-01-01     A1     B1     C1
2019-01-02     A2     B2     C1
2019-01-03     A2     B2     C1
2019-01-04     A1     B1     C2
2019-01-05     A1     B1     C3
2019-01-05     A1     B1     C1
2019-01-06     A1     B1     C3
2019-01-07     A1     B1     C1
```

becomes

```
2019-01-01     A1     B1     C1
2019-01-02     A2     B2     C1
2019-01-04     A1     B1     C2
2019-01-05     A1     B1     C3
2019-01-05     A1     B1     C1
2019-01-07     A1     B1     C1
```

Does a second pass now need made to remove the `2019-01-07` entry?
Are you going to run the query repeatedly until no rows are affected?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that the TimeOfChange values are all unique. So your answer should work on a single pass.

Comment: If time of change is unique, you may be able to simplify that query further.